# Readability of the new 'already has an answer' banner

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, design

I suggest a trivial layout change that would (IMO) greatly improve readability. The current layout shows the banner inside the question body; this banner stands where the old “*possible duplicates*” banner was. This placement is, and has always been, extremely confusing, especially to new users who might not realize at all that this banner isn't part of the original question. I believe it's time to change this oddity, and suggest the top banner be aligned with the bottom one as sketched here:

[image: banner alignment]

Please do not intrude the posts' bodies! This would obviously make the SE network a better place.

Comment: The old **Possible Duplicate:** box was always in the post body and nobody complained.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - however as the screens have chgnaed people will look at things again and see other areas for change

Comment: @Bolt true, but now that the text is no longer injected into the post such change looks more proper. (Not to mention much easier to implement)

Comment: I really like this idea; isn't this the ad space if you're not a user with reduced ads though?