# Why do some duplicate questions not refer to the original question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442758/why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class) is a question that I found that is marked as duplicate, but does not come with a link to the original question. Why did this happen? Is it a bug?

The main reason I put it here is because I believe this doesn't just happen on that particular question on that particular site -- since all sites use the same flagging system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why did this happen? Is it a bug?

The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10442758/timeline) shows that the duplicate link was edited out because the target duplicate question was removed:

[image]

Comment: Then that is a bug then. or the question should not be marked as a duplicate anymore since its apparent duplicate no longer exists!

Comment: +1 @Tuvia! Or maybe that feature doesn't exist yet?